# Loading JSON with D3 when columns are defined separately

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm using d3.js and I'm having hard time understanding how can I load a JSON which represents a table (columns and rows), which the columns are defined separately.

A normal JSON, which I have no problem loading may look like this:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A green door",
    "price": 12.50
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "A red door",
    "price": 12.50
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "A blue door",
    "price": 12.50
}
]
```

The corresponding JSON with separated columns will look like this:

```
{
    "columns": [
        {
            "ColumnName":"id",
            "DataType":"number"
        },
        {
            "ColumnName":"name",
            "DataType":"string"
        },
        {
            "ColumnName":"price",
            "DataType":"number"
        }
    ],
    "rows": [
        [
            "1",
            "A green door",
            "12.50"
        ],
        [
            "2",
            "A red door",
            "12.50"
        ],
        [
            "3",
            "A blue door",
            "12.50"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to make d3.js load this kind of JSON without reconstructing a new JSON?

The original structure of the JSON that I receive is not changeable.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: do you want to change the second json to teh first json structure?

Answer (score 2):

There won't be any problem in loading the *JSON with separated columns*(Format 2) with d3. You will just need to convert the JSON format after loading it, to match the required format of your d3 layout. For that, you may try the code as shown below.

```
d3.json("path/to/column_json_file_name.json", function(error, data) {
  if (error) return console.warn(error);
  var columns = data.columns.map(function(d){ return d.ColumnName });
  var jsonInRquiredFormat = data.rows.map(function(row,i){ 
      var ob = {}; 
      ob[columns[0]] = parseInt(row[0]); 
      ob[columns[1]] = row[1]; 
      ob[columns[2]] = parseFloat(row[2]); 
      return ob; 
  });
  console.log(jsonInRquiredFormat);
});
```

Output obtained for sample input:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A green door",
    "price": 12.5
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "A red door",
    "price": 12.5
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "A blue door",
    "price": 12.5
}]
```

Comment: That's what I've done but I would like to avoid this.
When the original JSON contains 10K rows and every couple of seconds there might be another JSON to process, this procedure becomes really heavy.

Comment: Which d3 layout are you using?? force??

Comment: I'd like to use the one shown in their website 
http://square.github.io/crossfilter/

Comment: Oh.. I have not used it yet. So don't know whether it supports JSON in other formats... sry..